# Error in uploading marks Expected string but received array

Tags: javascript, react, validator

Estou com um projeto de gestão escolar, e na aba de "enviar chamadas" quando clico no botão para enviar o form com as presenças dos alunos da o erro **"Error in uploading marks Expected string but received array"**, já ouvi falar que é um problema com a lib validator para as validações, porém não estou conseguindo resolver esse erro.

**uploadMarks:**

```
    const Validator = require('validator');
const isEmpty = require('./is-empty');


const validateFacultyUploadMarks = (data) => {
    let errors = {}
    data.subjectCode = !isEmpty(data.subjectCode) ? data.subjectCode : '';
    data.exam = !isEmpty(data.exam) ? data.exam : '';
    data.totalMarks = !isEmpty(data.totalMarks) ? data.totalMarks : '';

    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.subjectCode)) {
        errors.subjectCode = 'Subject Code field is required';
    }

    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.exam)) {
        errors.exam = 'Exam field is required';
    }
    if (Validator.isEmpty(data.totalMarks)) {
        errors.totalMarks = 'Total marks field is required';
    }

    return {
        errors,
        isValid: isEmpty(errors)
    };

}


module.exports = validateFacultyUploadMarks
```

**teacherController:**

```
uploadMarks: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const { errors, isValid } = validateFacultyUploadMarks(req.body);

            // Check Validation
            if (!isValid) {
                return res.status(400).json(errors);
            }
            const {exam, totalMarks, marks, department, year } = req.body
            const isAlready = await Mark.find({ exam, department})
            if (isAlready.length !== 0) {
                errors.exam = "You have already uploaded marks of given exam"
                return res.status(400).json(errors);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
                const newMarks = await new Mark({
                    student: marks[i]._id,
                    exam,
                    department,
                    marks: marks[i].value,
                    totalMarks
                })
                await newMarks.save()
            }
            res.status(200).json({message:"Marks uploaded successfully"})
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log("Error in uploading marks",err.message)
        }
        
    },
```

**is-Empty:**

```
const isEmpty = value => 
    value === undefined ||
    value === null ||
    (typeof value === 'object' && Object.keys(value).length === 0) ||
    (typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length === 0);

   

module.exports = isEmpty;
```

Answer (score -2):

De acordo com a biblioteca [Validator](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js), o método `isEmpty` espera receber uma string como parâmetro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
No trecho que você disponibilizou, você está enviando para Validator.isEmpty() algum array

- `data.subjectCode`
- `data.exam`
- `data.totalMarks`

Em:

```
const validateFacultyUploadMarks = (data) => {
 let errors = {}
 data.subjectCode = !isEmpty(data.subjectCode) ? data.subjectCode : '';
 data.exam = !isEmpty(data.exam) ? data.exam : '';
 data.totalMarks = !isEmpty(data.totalMarks) ? data.totalMarks : '';

 if (Validator.isEmpty(data.subjectCode)) {
    errors.subjectCode = 'Subject Code field is required';
 }

 if (Validator.isEmpty(data.exam)) {
    errors.exam = 'Exam field is required';
 }
 if (Validator.isEmpty(data.totalMarks)) {
    errors.totalMarks = 'Total marks field is required';
 }

 return {
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors)
 };
}
```

O erro é capturando no bloco try catch pela chamada da função

```
 const { errors, isValid } = validateFacultyUploadMarks(req.body);
```

Sugiro revisar qual dessas variáveis não é uma string ou não utilizar o método `Validator.isEmpty`, optando por usar a sua própria implementação de `isEmpty` para checagem.

Comment: Eu removi o validator e deixei só o isEmpty para checagem , só que agora ele dá erro 400(Bad request)

Comment: Verifica qual dado está inválido. O erro 404 ta sendo forçado caso `!isValid` por sua função `uploadMarks`. Poste o trecho de como ficou a atualização com a remoção do `isEmpty`.